# XPATH, grabbing content of next divs bases on textual value

Tags: html, xpath

I need to grab contact details of people that appears pretty much in the same bit of code after the words:

"For further information, please contact:"

So I want the href (http://www.wongpartnership.com/index.php/wongpartnership/partner/chan-hock-keng)

and the name (Hock Keng)

Tried variations of `//strong[contains(., 'For further')]/following-sibling::p`
but not working

Code:

```
<p><span style="font-size:14px;"><span data-mce-style="font-size: small;"><strong>For further information, please contact:</strong></span></span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span style="font-size:14px;"><span data-mce-style="font-size: small;"><strong><a data-mce-href="http://www.wongpartnership.com/index.php/wongpartnership/partner/chan-hock-keng" href="http://www.wongpartnership.com/index.php/wongpartnership/partner/chan-hock-keng" target="_blank">Hock Keng</a></strong><strong><a data-mce-href="http://www.wongpartnership.com/index.php/wongpartnership/partner/chan-hock-keng" href="http://www.wongpartnership.com/index.php/wongpartnership/partner/chan-hock-keng" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a></strong><strong><a data-mce-href="http://www.wongpartnership.com/index.php/wongpartnership/partner/chan-hock-keng" href="http://www.wongpartnership.com/index.php/wongpartnership/partner/chan-hock-keng" target="_blank">Chan</a></strong><strong>, Partner, WongPartnership</strong></span></span></p>
```